# One of the equality operators isn't working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, equality

(beginner here, I'm learning c#) I've just learned about equality operators and was testing one out. For some reason unbeknownst to me (it's probably some really simple mistake I'm overlooking) I'm getting an error. Here's the code:

```
string number = "number";
number == "number";
```

I'm getting an error for the line, `number == "number"`. To my knowledge, when I run it, "true" should be printed. Thanks for helping out a beginner, I'll probably be kicking myself once I know the answer.

Comment: If you want to print it then do `Console.WriteLine(number == "number");`

Comment: `number == "number"` is a condition. It's meaningless as a statement that's why the compiler is telling you that "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement".

Comment: When posting questions, please include the error message if you have any. I'm this case it was obvious what the problem was, but it may not always be

Answer (score 2):

In the second line you use the equality operator `==`. You correctly understand that the equality operator `==` returns `true` if its operands are equal, `false` otherwise. Thus, it returns a value of type `bool`. But to output the result of this operation to the console, you should use the method `Console.WriteLine`. So you should first save this value in a variable and then output the value of this variable to the console. This can be done like this:

```
string number = "number";
bool equalityComparisonResult = number == "number";
Console.WriteLine(equalityComparisonResult);
```

Or you can do without an intermediate variable and print the result of the equality directly to the console:

```
string number = "number";
Console.WriteLine(number == "number");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string number = "number";
number == "number"? Console.WriteLine("numbers are equal"): Console.WriteLine("numbers are different");
```

or you can use Equals Method:

```
string number = "number";
number.Equals("number")
```